# Dojo Datagrid not rendering json data

Tags: json, spring-mvc, dojo

I have a spring mvc based app that returns me a list of products which I wish to render in a **dojo datagrid**.I have used a **org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver** that uses 
**MappingJackson2JsonView** as the default view.

Here is my spring view configuration

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">  
  <property name="mediaTypes">  
    <map>  
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>  
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>  
    </map>  
  </property>     
  <property name="defaultViews">  
    <list>  
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">  
      </bean>  
    </list>  
</property>  
</bean>
```

this is my basic dojo script

```
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/store/JsonRest",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojo/store/Cache",
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
        "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
        /*"dojo/query",*/
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query){
        var myStore, dataStore, grid;
        myStore = Cache(JsonRest({target:"products.do"}), Memory());
        alert("MyStore : "+JSON.stringify(myStore));
        grid = new DataGrid({
            store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
            structure: [
                {name:"Id", field:"id", width: "200px"},
                {name:"Description", field:"description", width: "200px", editable: true},
                {name:"Price", field:"price", width: "200px"},
                {name:"Category", field:"category", width: "200px", editable: true}                     
            ]
        }, "gridDiv"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
        grid.startup();
        alert("DataStore : "+JSON.stringify(dataStore));
    });
</script>
```

There is no javascript error however all that i see is a empty grid.
On checking with Firebug I see this in the response

[image]

So my serverside to front end hookup seems to be correct.What is not clear to me is despite this the grid doesn't reflect any rows.Why could this be happening?What am I missing or doing wrong?Do let me know if any other relevant bit of information is required

Comment: I don't think this is the source of your issue, but you should be creating your Cache, JsonRest, and Memory stores with the `new` keyword. Worth a try to see if that resolves anything. On a side note, if you aren't restricted to using Dojo's DataGrid, you should check out SitePen's new [dgrid project](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/). It is meant to replace DataGrid and in my experience works a LOT better (and looks nicer too). [Here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid) is the github repository for it.

Comment: whats the error ? could you try to hook up your json data without cache & memory first ?